# How can I make an HTML element's width adjust to the size of the margin?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a rectangular button using CSS and HTML. Sometimes there will be more than one line of text in the button, but other times it may only be a few words. I want to make the width of the button stay the same regardless of the text inside of it, and I want the text to be centered inside of the button. The button has 5% margins on either side, so I guess I want the button width to be 90%, but this didn't work when I tried it. I thought the % measurement was a percent of the width of the browser window, but now I'm not sure. Anyway, I want the text background to stretch out all the way to the margins on either side, and the text to be centered in the middle of the button (FYI when I say button, I'm not talking about the HTML tag, I'm talking about a button I made using a link)

Here is the code for a button I want to stretch out to the margins:

```
<a href="separatePage.html" class="button" style="position:absolute;
    margin-top:255px;
    margin-left:5%;
    margin-right:5%;
    background-color:rgb(24, 90, 212);
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:2.5%;
    border-radius:25px;
    border-style:inset;
    border-color:white;
    border-width:4px;
    text-decoration:none;">I want this button to stretch out to the margins</a>
```

Also, if you can't tell, I am pretty new to coding, so if you notice something else I could be doing better, please LMK. I would appreciate any advice from a more experienced coder.

Answer (score 0):

if your are tring to make button use input tag and give it width and height so if will more comfortable to you and if you want to give background color give that tag  style and set the buttton and that position using margin proper. :

Comment: Please show us an image of what you expect to make.

Comment: <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>

Comment: i noticed a lot of grammatical error and typo there so please fix them to make it better for us to read